# BLDC BEMF not right

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I am trying to build my own ESC (brushless DC controller) and I managed to get the motor running starting from a ramp to a steady PWM duty Cycle and Commutation period and these are the BEMF waveforms that I see. My question is, where is the "zero crossing event" and why is it different (somehow inverted) from the regular BEMF waveforms displayed on various application notes?

Please refer to the images below:

[image]
[image]

Here-in, it is almost impossible to detect '0' crossing. Also, in my scheme I am PWMing the upper MOSFETS, with the lower ones being used/made high during relevant commutations.

Comment: What, in reference to your scope pictures, are you expecting to see precisely?

Comment: Sir, the signals during the float phase are inverted. where there is a rise, it should be a decay and vice-versa.

Comment: My name isn't "sir"!! Given that not many folk are interested in answering this question, I would make what you've said a lot clearer in the question rather than in a comment. I'm not sure what the float phase is so I'm still in the dark. Please don't try and explain this to me - try and reinforce your question to attract someone who can grasp what you are saying.

Comment: I'd start by putting the scope (and maybe a resistor) on one of motor's phases without any driver attached and spinning it by hand.  You should see a (roughly) sine wave coming out and you'll naturally see zero crossing.  With the phases actively driven what you should see is a modulation over your bus voltage and sensing the motor's phase becomes more complicated.

Comment: and how do I connect gnd for the oscilloscope.

Comment: Connect gnd to your circuit ground, or alternately use three resistors in a star configuration with center as ground.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as you had.
Can you please explain me what is causing this problem?
And how did you solve this problem?

Comment: @RoeltenHave
I have answered below. Cld not comment as it was too long. Ping if you still have doubts pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This business of starting from scratch is exceedingly difficult.  Something about your waveforms looks wrong, but with phase descriptions how can we know exactly?

I make a guess that you are commutating wrong, perhaps as well pwming the low side.  Generally with correct commutation the zero cross part of the commutation shows a rise at pwm hits rather than a fall as yours are showing. Also, it seems odd that the low is riding up around 1-2 volts during certain commutation periods.

I have added some waveforms scope shots from a working esc.  Although there appear to be issues, this is driving the motor.  Note the rise from zero evident at the zero crossing period.

[image: 500us div]  [image: 200 us div]

Also, don't forget that sampling has to be synced with your pwm.

My start with BLDC began with [this kit](http://www.microchip.com/Developmenttools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=DM330021-2).  Can't you find a similar kit, so that you have a known good reference point?  If your or your boss cannot afford this kit..  Then this is the price of learning perhaps?

Comment: thank you sir. This is ,I guess, when it goes into the closed loop commutation with '0' crossing. What about when it is in open loop. Will it show the same waveforms that I showed in the images above.

Comment: BTW, how r u doing the PWM. Is the PWMs on high MOSFET , with low ones on for relevant state.

Comment: open vs closed won't make that difference.  Judging by the scope shots, your motor isn't hardly running, is it? PWM is on high mosfet only.

Comment: Sir, based on ur inputs I am able to get the same waveform using an open loop setup. I am yet not looking for the '0' crossing and stuff. So I am hard coding the commutation time and duty cycle. Then I vary the comm time value till I got this waveform.

Comment: My commutation waveforms are "inverted" from what you show here, @ErikFriesen, in your response --and I can't figure out how to replicate what you show..  Ie, instead of referenced to GND, they're referenced to the Positive rail (VBAT) .   This kind of makes sense to me, since the commutation scheme connects each phase to VBAT for 120deg, while PWMming  one of the other phase connections at a time for 60deg -- so it makes sense the the scope shows the waveforms "going down" from the VBAT rail.  So, what is the set up to get the waveforms as you show on your response?  What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question about GND vs VBAT reference.  I simply connected the scope to the outputs, and all is referenced to GND.  Its hard to answer your setup question, perhaps you need to ask your own question with pictures and all.

Answer (score 2):

@RoeltenHave. I had this problem for some time and eventually solved it. I presume that you are getting the same waveform shown in the pics.RIght ? This happens because the commutation between the states is not happening at the precise moment. Imagine a person running from one end of a hall to another  end. The whole path is littered with doors. The moment the nears a door it should be opened. Or else he wld bang himself and loose momentum in the process. I suggest the following approach -
1) Use a timer to measure the commutation. Start the commutation time from a large value (say abt 100msecs,this depends on motor as well). Let the duty cycle be a max of 10-15% as we dont want to draw too large a current. This timer will make the motor commutate from state x to state y ( where x and y - 0,1,2,3,4,and 5).
2) Let the commutation timer be reduced after say 4-5 iterations. In other words, for eg - let the commutation timer t1 = 100msecs. Let the motor run in state 0 (for eg) for 100msecs. Then jump to state 1 and so on for for 4-5 iterations. After that reduce the commutation time from 100msecs to a lower value. Kindly note. If you jump from 100msecs to drastically low value of say 10mses or so might stop the motor. This differs from motor to motor.
3) Consecutively keep lowering the commutation time interval and respect the iteration count. Keep it going loow till about 100uSecs.

Now, somewhere between 100mSecs and 100uSecs you will see the classical BLDC commutation waveform. When it happens depends on the load you provide. If there is no load we can see that desired waveform at a few 100s of uSecs (like 700uSecs). 
Now, we have seen the waveform. Next we need to automate the detection process. I am using the ADC of my uC to detect it. I am measuring the BEMF during the on time of the PWM. You have to detect the zero crossing (in thius case half of the Vcc i.e - Vcc/2).
Be careful of the low pass filter selected for the feedback to th adc. I have bypassed the LPF . My design the phase voltage is fed to the adc via a simple voltage regulator only. The LPF can cause attenuation.
Hope these help. DOnt hesitate to ask if u need more assistance.
WHEW !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Zero crossing event has to be detected between phase voltage and virtual winding centre, most common way is using the 9-resistor method, as in [this schematic](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-hASxsFGn4QU/UjkSqYfqSiI/AAAAAAAAliA/MPfF4Xrc5WE/s1600/TowerPro25aEscSchematic.png). Output from the three resistors on the left (R21-R23) is used as comparator reference because it provides voltage that is exactly halfway between two phase voltages (but only at the moment of zero-crossing).

To get it working you need to switch comparator inputs at every commutation. Important thing is to use comparator gating (aka windowing) i.e. watch for zero-crossing only during PWM on-time. That is the upper envelope of the waveform.

Your slopes are backwards because you are overdriving your motor. At this point, the zero crossing event occurs before the phase is unpowered and will appear to be stuck  to a point immediately following commutation. Try ramping up RPM until the crossing starts to move towards centre of the period and the slope gets its expected shape.