# BEMF polarity is backwards

Tags: motor, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, back-emf

Please take a look at this waveform of a 3 phase, BLDC motor:

[image]

Check out that rising and THEN falling slope...Pretty nice.

Now, take a look at what I'm getting on my motors sensorless resistor divider(s):

[image]

Not bad, but the BEMF is backwards...It rises when it falls, and it falls when it should rise.

I've tried manually commutating this thing from hundreds of mS all the way down to uS, where it freezes...Nothing seems to get this thing to turn around.

I've taken the advice from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/111809/bldc-bemf-not-right), but nothing seemed to straighten this out.

I've inverted the PWM/GNDing phases for each of the 6 commutations steps, and that didn't change anything.  I've tried physically swapping the phases on the output terminals...nothing there (not that I would have expected it to....I would have just expected the motor to run backwards).

What causes this?

**EDIT**

Here are some schematics of what I have going on here:
[image]

And here's a logic trace of the noninverted outputs from the micro to the gate driver.  Keep in mind that each of these has a complimentary output as well, to let the gate driver pull the phase high or low, but that signal isn't shown here... But, trust me, it's there.

[image]

Comment: Could you show a rough schematic of your sense resistors with respect to ground and the motor phases?

Comment: Edited... Im concerned about how short phase B lasts compared to A and C

Comment: That is a valid concern.  Running sensorless, do you make a speed adjustment on each phase, or only on one phase?  Also, what is the time increment that you can make on each speed adjustment?

Comment: Hi John, as of right now, I'm not making any speed adjustments.  All I'm saying is:  when you go above or below a virtual ground, aka the average of all motor phase voltages, start integrating the adc measurement of the floating phase until it crosses a threshold... Then, commutation.  I'm trying to do something similar to what TI does with their instaspin solution, where instead of adding a delay for commutation after detecting a second crossing, the just integrate the voltages over time to get flux, and once the Flux is where it should be, they use that as a trigger to commutate

Comment: But, this should be going as fast or as slow as it wants to... I'm just watching for zero crossings, waiting a certain delta of time and then commutation... No control is being exerted on the system besides that

Comment: I also have some waveforms that I captured from the Adc that I can post when I get back to the computer

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are wrong to position energized phases after bemf falling. You should energize windings first of descending phase of bem. Provably the detection circuit dont work well , filter capacitance too big and therefore delay